# icons are not displaying after setting up content delivery network for static view files?

Tags: magento2, cdn

I am trying to setup azure cdn for static view files and changed  Base URL for Static View Files with cdn url.but icons are not displaying ,how do i solve this ? I am using nginx server  and I  found out its font awesome cors problem .where do I wanna make changes ?

I am pointed my cdn to /pub/static

Comment: Have you changed js and css url? post your broken image  url here

Comment: no changes to js or css url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these happen to be font awesome icons? If so you might want to see this for enabling CORS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762484/enabling-cors-for-website-on-azure-cdn-to-host-fonts

Or you can pull your font awesome icons from a public HTTP/2 CDN that hosts font awesome for free and already supports CORS: https://fontawesomecdn.com/

```
https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.5.0/font-awesome.min.css
```